# How to change nullable values to not null values in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server-2008, union

I have merged three tables using union query and created group by function for all the columns.

Here is my code:

```
select 
    Id,
    Firstname,
    Mark1, Mark2, Mark3                                               
from
    (select
         Id, Firstname, Null as Mark1, Null as Mark2, Null as Mark3 
     from 
         Parent       
     union                                                                            
     select 
         Id, Null as Firstname, Mark1, Mark2, Null as Mark3 
     from 
         Child                 
     union                                                                            
     select 
         Id, Null as Firstname, Null as Mark1, Null as Mark2, Mark3 
     from 
         Mark) t 
where 
    Mark3 is not null                                                                                                        
group by 
    Id, Firstname, Mark1, Mark2, Mark3
```

Here I have set `mark3` is not null using where condition so my question is how to change null value to not null for rest of the fields using where condition?

Answer (score 0):

From your query I suggest to use join instead of (union with null values)
So try this

```
Select parent.Id , parent. firstName, child.mark1,child.mark2,mark.mark3
From parent 
inner join child on parent.id =child.id
Inner join mark on mark.id=parent.id
```